# typeError: destroy is not a function nextjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-effect

When I upgraded nextjs application from 9 to 12. There were some errors shown, that were not being taken take care of in previous version. One of them was: `typeError: destroy is not a function`

In the console I could see it mentioned `next-dev.js?3515:25 Warning: useEffect must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up. You returned null. If your effect does not require clean up, return undefined (or nothing`

Not sure it was because of the update nextjs has become too strict during it's checking, but I will put it down the solution for myself and everyone.

Answer (score 21):

In almost all of the cases this error occurs when you tried to return anything from your useEffect hook that is not a function.

The fault,

```
useEffect(() => someFunction());
```

or

```
useEffect(() => {
   return someFunction();
});
```

The Fix,

```
useEffect(() => {
   someFunction();
});
```

For more information read the following article,

https://typeofnan.dev/fix-uncaught-typeerror-destroy-is-not-a-function-in-react/

Answer (score 3):

I also got the same issue, i was upgraded my Next App from v9 to v12. And i found it because the useEffect

My code before was like (my Next v9) =

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      removeEventListener("blur", updateWarning);

      const inputFile = document.getElementById("input-file-ujian");
      if (inputFile) {
        inputFile.removeEventListener("click", (e) => {
          window.removeEventListener("blur", updateWarning);
        });
        inputFile.removeEventListener("change", handleChange);
      }

      const videos = document.getElementsByClassName("note-video-clip");
      for (let i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        videos[i].removeEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
          window.addEventListener("blur", updateWarning);
        });
        videos[i].removeEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
          window.removeEventListener("blur", updateWarning);
        });
      }
    };
  }, [pesertaUjian, warning]);
```

and this is my Next v12 (I remove the return code) =

```js
useEffect(() => {
      removeEventListener("blur", updateWarning);

      const inputFile = document.getElementById("input-file-ujian");
      if (inputFile) {
        inputFile.removeEventListener("click", (e) => {
          window.removeEventListener("blur", updateWarning);
        });
        inputFile.removeEventListener("change", handleChange);
      }

      const videos = document.getElementsByClassName("note-video-clip");
      for (let i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        videos[i].removeEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
          window.addEventListener("blur", updateWarning);
        });
        videos[i].removeEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
          window.removeEventListener("blur", updateWarning);
        });
      }
  }, [pesertaUjian, warning]);
```

I don't know why, I just remove all my return code in my useEffect and it's work for me

Update:
Update, i found that if you are using useEffect and async await. Don't use like it

```js
useEffect(async() => {},[])
```

but you can create function async await outside the useEffect, for example

```js
const yourFunction = async () => {}

useEffect(() => yourFunction(),[])
```

Answer (score 2):

There were a lot of place in the code which I am maintining where useEffect was returning `null` like:

````
useEffect(() => {
   if (variantSelected) {
     const productViewTrackingTimeout = setTimeout(
       useProductViewTracking({
        ...blah blah
       }),
       1000
     );
     return () => {
       clearTimeout(productViewTrackingTimeout);
     };
   }
   return null;
 }, [variantSelected, productTitle, router]);```

I removed all return null values, and just putting a return works too. But not any value.
````

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error when updating from react 17 to 18, but in my case it was caused by the function in a `useEffect` being async. Removing async/await and switching to `.then(result => {...}` fixed it for me.

Eks:
Code that failed

```
useEffect(async () => {
  const result = await fetchData()
  // Do stuff
})
```

Code that works

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData().then(result => {
    // Do stuff
  })
})
```